# What are the total number of action potentials in the human brain?

Tags: neuroscience, brain, synapses

Is there an approximate figure of the total number of action potentials in the human brain? It's my understanding that there are ~ 60 billion neurons in the brain with ~ 100 trillion connections between them. Plus there are graded responses between those connections. Is there an estimated figure for what the total might be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If firing rate is from 1 Hz to 200 Hz, 100 trillion to 20 quadrillion synaptic firings. Neuronal (say, measured from soma) firings  will add up to 86 billion to 17.2 trillion action potentials per second.

It important to remember, that synaptic firings "sum up" in soma or interfere between each other, so the are more of those.
Read more: http://neuroblog.stanford.edu/?p=4541

Comment: Awesome, thank you! I will check out the link.